# AndEngine load TiledTextureRegion from external storage or Bitmap source

Tags: android, animation, sprite, andengine

I am trying to dynamically create a sprite sheet in AndEngine, but I have searched high and low and for some reason can't find any instance of this ever being done. I need to create an AnimatedSprite from either a series of PNG's or a sprite sheet located at an external storage location and NOT prepackaged from assets. I need to get IBitmapTextureAtlasSource from an external file, or FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource. This has to be possible, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it and digging through classes, I decided to use BaseBitmapAtlasSourceDecorator to draw the dynamically created bitmap on an EmptyBitmapTextureAtlasSource with canvas and create a TiledTextureRegion.